# Which codes should I choose for legal exit from Windows Phone Applications?

Tags: windows-phone

I have 7 applications in Windows Phone Marketplace but I have a problem. My dashboard shows me crash reports about my QuitException (I have found it from stackoverflow) for using exiting from my applications. Which one is the legal exit from applications? Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override OnBackKeyPress

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it legal? Will my applications send me crash reports again, if I use this codes?